# React bootstrap Typeahead error on backspace

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

Im using react Bootstrap Typeahead in my code, problem is whenever I use backspace to remove my selection and when I reach a point where there is no letter, my code breaks and I get below error.
**Uncaught Invariant Violation: One or more options does not have a valid label string. Check the `labelKey` prop to ensure that it matches the correct option key and provides a string for filtering and display.

My Typeahead Code :

```
<Typeahead
  id="empName"
  options={this.state.EmployeeNameOptions}
  selected={[this.state.EmployeeName]}
  placeholder="Enter Employee Name"                  
  style={{ zIndex: 9999999 }}                    
  onInputChange={text => {                      
    this.setState({
      EmployeeName: text,
    })                                         
  }}
  onChange={(e, val) => {
    this.handleChange(e, val);
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `onInputChange` and `onChange` incorrectly. Every time you type inside the input, `onInputChange` is updating your state and changing the value for `selected`, leading to unexpected results. Meanwhile, `onChange` provides an array of the selected values its argument, not an event and value. Try the following instead:

```
<Typeahead
  ...
  options={this.state.EmployeeNameOptions}
  selected={this.state.selectedEmployee}
  onChange={(selected) => {
    this.setState({ selectedEmployee: selected });
  }}
/>
```